# Allowed energy levels in an $E$-$k$ diagram

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, density-of-states

For a particle confined in an infinite potential well in 1D, the $k$ value is quantized as $k=nπ/a$, where $a$ is the length of the region where $V(x)=0$. However, the $E$-$k$ diagram derived from Kronig-Penney model is drawn for continuous range of $k$, and the range of energy values corresponding to the continuous range of $k$ is referred to as 'allowed energy bands'. Why are all these energy values allowed while the $k$ values are supposed to be quantized as $k=nπ/a$. Is it because electrons interact with each other?

Comment: The potential wells in the Kronig-Penney model are of finite depth. Why are you comparing them to the infinite well?

Answer (score 2):

When using periodic (or Born-von Karman) boundary conditions, the allowed values of $k$ are $k = n\pi/L$, where $L$ is the size of the system under consideration. When $L$ is large (and in many cases the periodic boundary conditions only really make sense when this is true), the spacing of possible $k$ values gets smaller, so to a good approximation, $k$ can be considered a continuous variable. This has the additional advantage of eliminating the system size from the dispersion relations: for sufficiently large systems, the exact size is often irrelevant.